# Nativescript-Vue axios call error on local laravel API [Request failed with status code null]

Tags: javascript, android, ios, vue.js, nativescript

I'm fairly new to Nativescript, in my project I'm trying to make an http request to my local laravel server I set up with php artisan serve on http://127.0.0.1:8000/, I'm using a connected android device, no emulator. After some reading I got my local IPv4 with ipconfig command.

In my App.vue component I fire a GET request to my local laravel API endpoint with axios:

This DOESN'T work:

```
console.log('Firing axios call');
axios.get('http://192.168.1.35:8000/api/posts')
.then((response) => {
    console.log('It worked! /////////////////////////////////////////');
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log('God dammit',err);
});
```

But I always get error:

```
'God dammit' [Error: Request failed with status code null]
```

In laravel, this is my controller methos which responds to /api/posts

```
public function list(Request $request)
    {
        $posts = Post::with(['postcategory','author'])
            ->latest()
            ->paginate($request->input('paginate', 10));

        return response()->json([
            'data' => $posts,
            'pagination' => [
                'total' => $posts->total(),
                'per_page' =>$posts->perPage(),
                'current_page' => $posts->currentPage(),
                'last_page' => $posts->lastPage(),
                'from' => $posts->firstItem(),
                'to' => $posts->lastItem()
            ]  
        ]);
    }
```

I tried with httpbin endpoint and I get response back, it works but my laravel API never works...

This DOES work:

```
axios.get('https://httpbin.org/get')
.then((response) => {
   console.log('success');
   console.log(response.data);
}).catch((err)=>{
   console.log(err);
});
```

And returns:

```
{ args: {},
JS:   headers:
JS:    { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
JS:      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
JS:      Host: 'httpbin.org',
JS:      'User-Agent': 'Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; GT-I9060I Build/KTU84P)' },
JS:   origin: '79.152.179.88, 79.152.179.88',
JS:   url: 'https://httpbin.org/get' }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are your device and pc on the same wifi? Also, port 80 is default http, you don't need to add it.

Comment: Yes, they are on the same wi-fi

Comment: Can you try exposing on port :80 (or omitting port at all) and just connect to the ip address? Also try first to reach your pc by pinging to exclude issues related to axios: https://superuser.com/questions/586469/how-to-ping-an-ip-address-from-an-android-device

Comment: First, you should simplify your get request to something that isn't a paginated result. Just return ['message' => 'success']. Second, why are you are hosting on 127 but requesting to 192? I use homestead and it works for me. But when I had a bad laptop I had to test on production server. You could also make a staging server and test on that.

Comment: @Trace I pinged my IP, 4 packets sent and received, I tried ommiting the ports but I'm getting the same error

Comment: @Dazzle I read on local you can't connect as localhost but have to use my connected PC IP instead, smeone correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: What happens if you make the exact same call from your own pc (not the external device) on the given endpoint? (localhost)

Comment: @Trace you mean from my own laravel app via axios? it returns expected data

Comment: I mean from an api client on your desktop (e.g. Postman) to your localhost-laravel api (same machine). It also fails?

Comment: @Trace After downloading Postman and trying with GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts I get the expected results

Comment: Only thing I can think of right now... are you sure that you're connecting to the correct IP address? Although the ping works, I believe it should work. Have done this in the past with a native Android app installed on the device, and it worked. Can't remember I did something special aside from that. Perhaps your firewall? Out of ideas otherwise.

Comment: Which version of Android you are testing it with, If it's v9 or later, you will have to enable clear text traffic to support http request.

Comment: Yeah I enabled clearText, so I decided to deploy my laravel API in production, I tested the same api call and it works! still can't do it locally tho...

Comment: If you hit with the same local IP on POSTMAN does it give you the correct response?

Comment: did you find any solution to this @gabogabans?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using http, you need to add this to your app/App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml in the application tag:
**android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"**

like this:

```
<application ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```